# How to read 2 different dataframes from single CSV file in R?

Tags: r, csv, parsing, dataframe

Suppose we have 2 dataframes like this in single CSV file as:

```
Name C1 C2 C3 C4

aa   1   2  3  4

bb   3   4  6  5

cc  10   2  5  6

TT  44   2  2  6

#

Name C1 C2 C3 C4

aa   1   2  3  4

bb   3   4  6  5

cc  10   2  5  6

TT  44   2  3  6
```

My actual requirement is to read these 2 dataframes in 2 different dataframe variables, I want to analyze these 2 dataframes and plot accordingly, please help me in this regard.

Comment: How are they organized in the csv file? Is it 8 columns and you want two times four or is it x rows then new data and another X rows.

Comment: @DanielWinkler : Its in same order as written above, yes these are 2  different data frames for some same use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example

```
writeLines(
con = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"), 
text = "Name C1 C2 C3 C4
aa 1 2 3 4
bb 3 4 6 5
cc 10 2 5 6
TT 44 2 2 6
#
Name C1 C2 C3 C4
aa 1 2 3 4
bb 3 4 6 5
cc 10 2 5 6
TT 44 2 3 6")

txt <- readLines(tf)
sep <- grep("^#", txt)[1]
df1 <- read.table(text = txt[1:(sep-1)], header = TRUE)
df1$part <- "1"
df2 <- read.table(text = txt[(sep+1):length(txt)], header = TRUE)
df2$part <- "2"

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  gather(var, val, -part, -Name) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = val, fill = var)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~part)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Luke : Please review , i tried your way but something i am missing still, attaching the code and sample csv, thanks in advance